# In Seasonal Decompose Seasonal plot seems off

Tags: time-series, statsmodels, decomposition

When I decompose my time-series Seasonal plot looks like this, what have I could do wrong? Here is code that i used for decomposition

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

decomposition = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(temp_df['depth_to_groundwater'], model='additive', freq=12)

fig = decomposition.plot()
fig.set_figwidth(12)
fig.set_figheight(8)
fig.suptitle('Decomposition of time series')
plt.show()
```

Talking about my time series data it is negative, , maybe it could have influenced the plot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K77MC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase your freq. 12 is probably too low for your model. A freq like 365 would solve it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).